# Converting single digit to more than 2digits

Tags: c#, numbers, long-integer

I'am having a number and Its length will be more than 10digits, So that i can't save it in an  INTEGER variable. So i saved it in a LONG variable. Now the Problem is, while adding a number with that LONG Variable it returns a Round value. I'm working in C#.

*For Eg:*

```
long empId = 00000000001; 
long answer = empId + 1;  //  00000000001 + 1 = 2;
// answer == 2;
```

but expected answer is " 00000000002", How to achieve this..

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: You seem to have a problem understanding the difference between a value and its string representation.

Comment: use String.Format( "{0:0000000000}" , answer).. It should pad it with zeroes

Comment: Indeed... 00000000001 == 1 and 1 + 1 == 2 and 00000000002 == 2... so the problem is not C#, but your desire to format it with leading zeros (leading zeros have no effect on a number).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using `empId.ToString("D11")` if you want your number to be padded with zeroes to the left until there's a total of 11 figures. This is only a string representation of the `System.Int64` (also called `long` in C#).

Comment: Thanks.. Above answer also correct, but in my scenario this answer helps me.. Thank you all..

Answer (score 3):

When you're talking about numbers, `00000000002` and `2` represent the exact same thing. If you want a `string` representation of that number padded with zeroes then try something like this:

```
answer.ToString().PadLeft(11, '0');
```

That will ensure that the string is at least 11 characters long and will fill in empty spaces with zeroes.

Comment: I would better go for answer.ToString("000000000#")

Comment: @SoMoS You could also use `String.Format`. There's plenty of ways to do this, and for the given situation I don't think any of them have a distinct advantage.

Comment: Agree. I just meant that String.Format looks like a more common way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The leading 0s are not significant, they're not part of the numeric value. It's just a formatting artifact. If you want to keep the 0s, convert the numbers back to string with the adequate format string.

```
long value = ...
string s = value.ToString("0000000000");
```

Comment: @Mr47, what do you mean? "0000000000" is the proper format string to use to format the value with 10 digits with leading zeros

Comment: My mistake; bit too quick to comment... :)

Answer (score 1):

00000000002 and 2 are the same long values.  If you want to have zeros in the beginning, you can use the Long.ToString(string format) method:

```
string strAnswer = answer.ToString("00000000000");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string VALUE = answer.ToString("00000000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ints or the longs, then convert it to a string, and call [string.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx)

From the docs:

> Returns a new string that right-aligns the characters in this instance
>   by padding them on the left with a specified Unicode character, for a
>   specified total length.

Answer (score 0):

You number 00000000001 is in fact just 1 if it is represented as a number.  If you want it to show multiple 0's in front, then I recommend using [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) when you are displaying it.  For example:

```
long empId = 00000000001; // Actually sets empID to 1

long answer = empId + 1; // 1 + 1 = 2

string formattedAnswer = 1.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0'); // Creates a string of "0000000001"
```